# How can I add the width to this callout or position to this particular callout?

Tags: reactjs, user-interface, react-redux, fluent-ui, fluentui-react

I am using CommandBarButton from Fluent UI, I am not sure why this callout is getting inside the screen scrollbar, I tried to give it CSS to fix the issue and it worked but I have 3-4 other callouts on the same page so they are also taking the same and UI is not looking good?
If anyone have something that would be very helpful.

[The code from where the callout is getting created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WuKua.png)